# how to allow input to have spaces?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, web

hey so I have a form that I add eventually to a json list, the input has to be english or numbers. I have this code below which works for me but when I submit something with two words I have an error.

```
// c1 = alter all english letters to check if input is in english
const english = /^[A-Za-z0-9.]*$/;
form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    // c1
    if(!english.test(seller_name.value)){
        alert("Bad input! Enter only English letters.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }else if(!english.test(seller_domain.value)){
        alert("Bad input! Enter only English letters.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
});
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```
// c1 = alter all english letters to check if input is in english
const english = /^[A-Za-z0-9.]*$/;
const space = " ";
const combined = english+space

form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    // c1
    if(!combined.test(seller_name.value)){
        alert("Bad input! Enter only English letters.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }else if(!combined.test(seller_domain.value)){
        alert("Bad input! Enter only English letters.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space to your RegEx.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9. ]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to add the \s to your regex definition in order to allow white spaces.

```
const english = /^[A-Za-z0-9.\s]*$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern might look like this:
`([a-zA-Z]+\s*)*`

- `[a-zA-Z]` - any a-z, A-Z character
- `+` 1 or more of the previous group
- `\s*` 0 or more spaces
- wrapped in `()*` to allow multiple

Nice [Regex cheatsheet](https://regexr.com/)

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="([a-zA-Z]+\s*)*" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```